# Specific SQL issue: How to select rows where ALL IDs match... (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, where-clause

I have this very specific problem which I can't even decide how to approach. So I have 3 tables in MySQL.

Table `recipe`: `id_recipe`| `name` | `text` | `picture`

Table `ingredients_recipe`: `id_rs` | `id_recipe`| `id_ingredients`

Table `ingredients`: `id_ingredient` | `name` | `picutre`

This is a site, where you select ingredients(so the input is 1 or more `id_ingredient`) and it should display three categories:

1. All recipes you can make right now (you have all the ingredients required for it)
2. All recipes where you are missing only 1 or 2 ingredients
3. All recipes where you are missing only 3 or 4 ingredients.

Can you help me with these 3 SQL selects? I'm pretty deadlocked right now. Thanks.

**SAMPLE DATA**: http://pastebin.com/aTC5kQJi

Comment: you must have tried something, right?

Comment: Sample data and expected output will help you to get the more exact answer.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result(s) - as well formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt(s).

Comment: My current attempt is very basic: `SELECT * 
FROM ingredients_recipe
WHERE ingredients_recipe.id_ingredient
IN ( 2, 5) 
GROUP BYingredients_recipe.id_recipe
LIMIT 0 , 30"` As you can see, this only selects recipes which have at least one ingredietn from the list (2, 5). I'm thinking of just processing the information in PHP instead of trying to do a SQL query. @kapil.dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your basic statement is already on the right track. You just need to do a little trick. You cannot compare them directly, but you can compare the count of ingredients:

```
SELECT id_receipe, count(id_rs) as ingredient_count 
   FROM ingredients_recipe 
   WHERE id_ingredient IN ( 2, 5) 
   GROUP BY id_recipe
```

This will give you the count of ingredients you have for each receipe. Now get the total amount of ingredients for each receipe

```
SELECT id_receipe, count(id_rs) as ingredient_count 
   FROM ingredients_recipe 
   GROUP BY id_recipe
```

an compare them. Taking the first query as a basis. You can easily get your three different categories out of this.

Comment: thank you, perfect solution. Pretty simple too! I need to check up on my SQL.